# Removing drive from LVM that has the /boot partition

Tags: boot, lvm

I have two drives `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` that are in a Volume Group with three volumes: `/boot`, `/root`, and `/home`, mounted respectfully.

If I remove `/dev/sda` after doing

```
# pvmove /dev/sda
# vgreduce $myVolGroup /dev/sda
```

Will that affect my boot-loader assuming all of the `/boot` volume was on `/dev/sda` and it was the initial install disk?

*I would really like to avoid surprises.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components to the boot loader: the first stage, which is written directly to the MBR-and-later-blocks and isn't on a filesystem anywhere, and the second stage/config files/kernel image/initrd, which is in `/boot`. `grub` at least (I'm assuming that's your bootloader, if not this may not apply) knows about lvm in its own right, and so can find a `/boot` which uses it and load configuration from there. Thus, on that level it shouldn't make a difference. However, if you plan to remove `/dev/sda` from the system, you need to ensure that the first stage is in at least one of the remaining block devices; you would probably use some invocation of `grub-install` for this.

Comment: So those commands won't break anything but unplugging `dev/sda` will.

Comment: Yes, assuming that the first-stage bootloader is installed on `/dev/sda`.